# Find all JSON files within S3 Bucket

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

is it possible to find all `.json` files within S3 `bucket` where the bucket itself can have multiple sub-directories ?

Actually my bucket includes multiple sub-directories where i would like to collect all JSON files inside it in order to iterate over them and parse specific key/values.

Comment: S3 is a flat object store, it doesn't have real directories and it means most operations are "recursive" by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution (uses the boto module):

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')  # Create the connection to your bucket
objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')['Contents']

files = filter(lambda obj: obj['Key'].endswith('.json'), objs)  # json only 
return files
```

The syntax for the `list_objects_v2` function in boto3 can be found here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2

Note that only the first 1000 keys are returned. To retrieve more than 1000 keys to fully exhaust the list, you can use the `Paginator` class.

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3')  # Create the connection to your bucket
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket')

files = []
for page in pages:
    for obj in page['Contents']:
        page_files = filter(lambda obj: obj['Key'].endswith('.json'), objs)  # json only
        files.extend(page_files)
return files
```

*Note*: I recommend using a function that uses `yield` to slowly iterate over the files instead of returning the whole list, especially if the number of json files in your bucket is extremely large.

Alternatively, you can also use the `ContinuationToken` parameter (check the boto3 reference linked above).

Comment: How about if there's over 1k? is it possible to retrieve all ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I've edited the post to include retrieving al files over 1k

Comment: Thanks lee, some people recommended to use Athena, do you've experince with it ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I have used Athena, yes, but I can't say I'm proficient at it, so I'm afraid you should ask someone else instead.